# In Oracle 11g, How to count number of rows in a table blocking by some sessions

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

My Oracle 11g database has a table, `FILE_CONTROL`, which looks like

```
file_id | file_path |  file_name  | status 
--------------------------------------------
       1   /my/path    myfile1.dat  COMPLETE
       2   /my/path    myfile2.dat  PENDING
       3   /my/path    myfile3.dat  COMPLETE
       4   /my/path    myfile4.dat  PENDING
       5   /my/path    myfile5.dat  PENDING
```

There are 2 daemons working on this table all the time.

Daemon `D1` inserts new rows into this table and set status to `'PENDING'`. Another daemon `D2` select from this table where status = `'PENDING'`, and change the status to `'COMPLETE'` when finishes processing the files.

I want to write a cron job that reports the number of `PENDING` files every hour, but I cannot use this SQL

```
select count(*) from FILE_CONTROL where status = 'PENDING'
```

because the daemons always block some rows in the table. And the blocking time can take up to more than 1 hour sometimes. I have no control over these daemons nor can I edit their source code, so I cannot change their behavior that blocking the table.

**Is it possible to count rows from this table by ignoring the blocked rows, I only want an approximate number of files.**

Comment: How do you know which rows are blocked or not?

Comment: Hi Boneist, I once  tried updating status of 'PENDING' rows to 'HOLD' at the time daemon D1 did not insert any rows for a while. Daemon D2 will not process any rows whose status <> 'PENDING'. At the time, I can select count(*) ... without any problem. But after I updatd some rows back to 'PENDING', the statement 'select count(*) ...' did not return any result until the daemon D2 finished processing the PENDING files. So I assume some rows are blocked, I do not know exactly which rows are.